# Why does boost::numeric::interval::widen not behave the same as manually applying the same logic

Tags: c++, boost, intervals

I have the following test code

```
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    using Interval = boost::numeric::interval<double>;
    using dbl = std::numeric_limits< double >;

    std::cout  << std::setprecision(dbl::max_digits10) << std::endl ;

    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        double lower = -j;
        double upper = j;
        double tol = 0.1;// 1e-12;

        Interval i{lower, upper};

        double lower_ = lower + tol;
        double upper_ = upper - tol;

        Interval i_ = widen(i, -tol);
        if (lower_ != i_.lower() || upper_ != i_.upper()) {
            std::cout 
            << " error "
            << lower_ << "," << upper_ 
            << "     " 
            << i_.lower() << "," << i_.upper() 
            << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
error -1.8999999999999999,1.8999999999999999     -1.9000000000000001,1.9000000000000001
 error -2.8999999999999999,2.8999999999999999     -2.9000000000000004,2.9000000000000004
 error -3.8999999999999999,3.8999999999999999     -3.9000000000000004,3.9000000000000004
 error -16.899999999999999,16.899999999999999     -16.900000000000002,16.900000000000002
 error -17.899999999999999,17.899999999999999     -17.900000000000002,17.900000000000002
 error -18.899999999999999,18.899999999999999     -18.900000000000002,18.900000000000002
 error -19.899999999999999,19.899999999999999     -19.900000000000002,19.900000000000002
 error -20.899999999999999,20.899999999999999     -20.900000000000002,20.900000000000002
 error -21.899999999999999,21.899999999999999     -21.900000000000002,21.900000000000002
 error -22.899999999999999,22.899999999999999     -22.900000000000002,22.900000000000002
 error -23.899999999999999,23.899999999999999     -23.900000000000002,23.900000000000002
 error -24.899999999999999,24.899999999999999     -24.900000000000002,24.900000000000002
 error -25.899999999999999,25.899999999999999     -25.900000000000002,25.900000000000002
 error -26.899999999999999,26.899999999999999     -26.900000000000002,26.900000000000002
 error -27.899999999999999,27.899999999999999     -27.900000000000002,27.900000000000002
 error -28.899999999999999,28.899999999999999     -28.900000000000002,28.900000000000002
 error -29.899999999999999,29.899999999999999     -29.900000000000002,29.900000000000002
 error -30.899999999999999,30.899999999999999     -30.900000000000002,30.900000000000002
 error -31.899999999999999,31.899999999999999     -31.900000000000002,31.900000000000002
 error -32.899999999999999,32.899999999999999     -32.900000000000006,32.900000000000006
 error -33.899999999999999,33.899999999999999     -33.900000000000006,33.900000000000006
 error -34.899999999999999,34.899999999999999     -34.900000000000006,34.900000000000006
 error -35.899999999999999,35.899999999999999     -35.900000000000006,35.900000000000006
 error -36.899999999999999,36.899999999999999     -36.900000000000006,36.900000000000006
 error -37.899999999999999,37.899999999999999     -37.900000000000006,37.900000000000006
 error -38.899999999999999,38.899999999999999     -38.900000000000006,38.900000000000006
 error -39.899999999999999,39.899999999999999     -39.900000000000006,39.900000000000006
 error -40.899999999999999,40.899999999999999     -40.900000000000006,40.900000000000006
 error -41.899999999999999,41.899999999999999     -41.900000000000006,41.900000000000006
 error -42.899999999999999,42.899999999999999     -42.900000000000006,42.900000000000006
 error -43.899999999999999,43.899999999999999     -43.900000000000006,43.900000000000006
 error -44.899999999999999,44.899999999999999     -44.900000000000006,44.900000000000006
 error -45.899999999999999,45.899999999999999     -45.900000000000006,45.900000000000006
 error -46.899999999999999,46.899999999999999     -46.900000000000006,46.900000000000006
 error -47.899999999999999,47.899999999999999     -47.900000000000006,47.900000000000006
 error -48.899999999999999,48.899999999999999     -48.900000000000006,48.900000000000006
 error -49.899999999999999,49.899999999999999     -49.900000000000006,49.900000000000006
 error -50.899999999999999,50.899999999999999     -50.900000000000006,50.900000000000006
 error -51.899999999999999,51.899999999999999     -51.900000000000006,51.900000000000006
 error -52.899999999999999,52.899999999999999     -52.900000000000006,52.900000000000006
 error -53.899999999999999,53.899999999999999     -53.900000000000006,53.900000000000006
 error -54.899999999999999,54.899999999999999     -54.900000000000006,54.900000000000006
 error -55.899999999999999,55.899999999999999     -55.900000000000006,55.900000000000006
 error -56.899999999999999,56.899999999999999     -56.900000000000006,56.900000000000006
 error -57.899999999999999,57.899999999999999     -57.900000000000006,57.900000000000006
 error -58.899999999999999,58.899999999999999     -58.900000000000006,58.900000000000006
 error -59.899999999999999,59.899999999999999     -59.900000000000006,59.900000000000006
 error -60.899999999999999,60.899999999999999     -60.900000000000006,60.900000000000006
 error -61.899999999999999,61.899999999999999     -61.900000000000006,61.900000000000006
 error -62.899999999999999,62.899999999999999     -62.900000000000006,62.900000000000006
 error -63.899999999999999,63.899999999999999     -63.900000000000006,63.900000000000006
```

Can somebody please explain why *widen* is not doing exactly the same as manually applying the widening to the limits.

See https://godbolt.org/z/fonMrGj74 for a live demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Root Cause

The problem is floating point inexact representation. If we simplify the test program and use a decimal representation, there is no issue:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43f1e53ef98e508a)**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    using T = boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50;
    using Interval = boost::numeric::interval<T>;
    using LIM      = std::numeric_limits<T>;

    std::cout << "Precision: " << LIM::max_digits10 << "\n"
              << std::setprecision(LIM::max_digits10);

    const T tol("0.1"); // 1e-12;

    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        T lower = -j;
        T upper = j;

        Interval const manual(lower - tol, upper + tol);
        Interval       library{lower, upper};
        library = widen(library, tol);

        using namespace boost::numeric::interval_lib::compare::lexicographic;

        if (library != manual)
            std::cout << " error " << manual << " vs " << library << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Done\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Precision: 80
Done
```

### Interval Policies & Rounding Modes

It looks like the naive manual implementation results in boundaries that are *closest* to the intended representation if the representation cannot be exact.

By contrast it looks like `widen` makes sure that if the result cannot be represented exactly, the widening is guaranteed to be **at least** the requested amount, never accidentally slightly less due to representation issues. This means that in these situations

- the widened lower bound may be lower than the manually calculated one
- the widened upper bound may be higher than the manually calculated one

The behaviour can be adjusted, because it comes from the **[rounding policy](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/rounding.htm)** which supplies `sub_down` and `add_up` primitives.

I would suggest [not to change it](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/rounding.htm#perf:%7E:text=if%20you%20need%20precise%20computations%20with%20the%20float%20or%20double%20types), though:

> if you need precise computations with the float or double types, use the default rounded_math;

`rounded_math<T>` is already the default.

If you insist on having identical results as the manual method (even if they are inferior):

```
using T        = double; // boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50;

namespace I    = boost::numeric::interval_lib;
using Interval = I::change_rounding<boost::numeric::interval<T>,
                                    I::rounded_arith_exact<T>>::type;
```

Prints **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a3eda7cfa36db59)**

```
Precision: 17
Done
```

### Further Caveats

There's a [documentation warning](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm#intro):

> **Warning!** Guaranteed interval arithmetic for native floating-point format is not supported on every combination of processor, operating system, and compiler.

There is a list of specific compiler quirks/flags you have to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
Boost is complicated and somewhere it sets the mode of the floating-point unit (FPU) which changes rounding behavior.

The answer by sehe is spot on but in case you are interested in a more technical answer then read on.

---

The lines of interest in your example are

```
  using Interval = boost::numeric::interval<double>;
  Interval i{lower, upper};
  Interval i_ = widen(i, -tol);
```

Let's go down the rabbit hole and try to understand how boost implements these lines.

---

The main class is

```
// boost/numeric/interval/interval.hpp:l.37
template<class T, class Policies>
class interval;
```

The template argument `Policies` gets its default value defined at

```
// boost/numeric/interval/detail/interval_prototype.hpp:l.27
template<class T>
struct default_policies
{
  typedef policies<rounded_math<T>, checking_strict<T> > type;
};
// <truncated>
template<class T, class Policies = typename interval_lib::default_policies<T>::type >
class interval;
```

The general `rounded_math` template is defined at

```
// boost/numeric/interval/rounding.hpp:l.93
template<class T>
struct rounded_math: save_state_nothing<rounded_arith_exact<T> >
{};
```

but we actually need to look at the explicit template specialization

```
// boost/numeric/interval/hw_rounding.hpp:l.59
template<>
struct rounded_math<double>
  : save_state<rounded_arith_opp<double> >
{};
```

The `save_state` template is a derived class from its argument, i.e.

```
// boost/numeric/interval/rounding.hpp:l.75
template<class Rounding>
struct save_state: Rounding
{
  typename Rounding::rounding_mode mode;
  save_state() {
    this->get_rounding_mode(mode);
    this->init();
  }
  ~save_state() { this->set_rounding_mode(mode); }
  typedef detail::save_state_unprotected<Rounding> unprotected_rounding;
};
```

Note here that `Rounding::init()` will be called (as well as `Rounding::set_rounding_mode(mode)` at destruction)!

Then lets have a look at `rounded_arith_opp`

```
// boost/numeric/interval/rounded_arith.hpp:l.78
template<class T, class Rounding>
struct rounded_arith_opp: Rounding {
  void init() { this->upward(); }
  // <truncated>
# define BOOST_UP(EXPR) return this->force_rounding(EXPR)
# define BOOST_UP_NEG(EXPR) return -this->force_rounding(EXPR)
  T sub_down(const T& x, const T& y) { BOOST_UP_NEG(y - x); }
  T add_up  (const T& x, const T& y) { BOOST_UP(x + y); }
  // <truncated>
};
```

Its default `Rounding` argument is defined at

```
// boost/numeric/interval/rounding.hpp:l.46
template<class T, class Rounding = rounding_control<T> >
struct rounded_arith_opp;
```

The rounding control is defined at

```
// boost/numeric/interval/rounding.hpp:l.20
template<class T>
struct rounding_control
{
  // <truncated>
  static const T& force_rounding(const T& x) { return x; }
};
```

It also has explicit template specializations which vary by platforms, e.g.

```
// boost/numeric/interval/detail/c99_rounding_control.hpp:l.28
template<>
struct rounding_control<double>:
  detail::c99_rounding_control
{
  static double force_rounding(double const &r)
  { volatile double r_ = r; return r_; }
};
```

The `c99_rounding_control` class implements the change of rounding modes, i.e.

```
// boost/numeric/interval/detail/c99sub_rounding_control.hpp:l.23
struct c99_rounding_control
{
  static void set_rounding_mode(rounding_mode mode)  { fesetround(mode); }
  static void get_rounding_mode(rounding_mode &mode) { mode = fegetround(); }
  static void upward()      { set_rounding_mode(FE_UPWARD);     }
  // <truncated>
};
```

Now we understand the `interval` class and can have a look at the `widen` function

```
// boost/numeric/interval/detail/c99_rounding_control.hpp:l.82
template<class T, class Policies> inline
interval<T, Policies> widen(const interval<T, Policies>& x, const T& v)
{
  if (interval_lib::detail::test_input(x))
    return interval<T, Policies>::empty();
  typename Policies::rounding rnd;
  return interval<T, Policies>(rnd.sub_down(x.lower(), v),
                               rnd.add_up  (x.upper(), v), true);
}
```

It creates the `rnd` object which will call in the end `c99_rounding_control::upward` and together with `rounded_arith_opp::{add_up,sub_down}` one gets the observed results.

---

I will supply a simple example to show how the rounding takes place ([godbolt-link](https://godbolt.org/z/rzErK4b3b))

```
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

double force_rounding(const double& r) {
  volatile double r_ = r;
  return r_;
}

int main() {
  cout << setprecision(numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10) << endl;

  auto tol = 0.1;
  const auto lower = -2;
  const auto upper = 3;

  cout << "default rounding:\t" << lower + tol << ", " << upper - tol << '\n';

  {
    using Interval = boost::numeric::interval<double>;
    const auto i = widen(Interval{lower, upper}, -tol);
    cout << "widen:\t\t\t" << i.lower() << ", " << i.upper() << '\n';
  }

  {
    boost::numeric::interval_lib::detail::c99_rounding_control::upward();
    const auto lower_ = -force_rounding(-lower - tol);
    const auto upper_ = force_rounding(upper - tol);
    cout << "set rounding:\t\t" << lower_ << ", " << upper_ << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
default rounding:       -1.8999999999999999, 2.8999999999999999
widen:                  -1.9000000000000001, 2.9000000000000004
set rounding:           -1.9000000000000001, 2.9000000000000004
```

---

See also

- boost doc about interval's rounding: [boost.org](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/rounding.htm)
- boost version: 1.79.0 (for line numbers)